# Disable UITableView scrolling on some cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, touch

In iOS 6, I have a UITableView, with pull to refresh enabled. In the top cell, I have a couple of customs controls which the user can interactive by dragging a circular slider (see this [example](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/how-to-build-a-custom-control-in-ios/)). See screenshot...

[image]

The control need a tag and dragging of the slider indicators need to be dragged but they can be tricky to grab as the hit seems to often be on the cell background, causing the table dragging to kick in.

I would like to disable the default scrolling of table if the tap event happens anywhere on those controls. Two options I can think off:

1. disable table dragging for any event within that top cell
2. make sure the controls handles events on an larger area, in particular in parts where they have a transparent background

Any suggestions on how to achieve either of these?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this :tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;

Comment: I understand that, my issues is that I want the table to be draggable and scrollable, except when touch events occur in the first row (in which case I want the event to go to the sliders only)

Answer (score 0):

I used to subclass of `UIControl` and override these functions:

```
override func continueTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool { }

override func endTracking(_ touch: UITouch?, with event: UIEvent?) {}

override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {}
```

It works fine for me of this circle slider style.

If still doesn't work you can try to turn on/off your tableView scrollable in the methods above.

```
tableView.isScrollEnabled = false / true
```